# Azure Boards Create report with Sum of effort

Tags: azure-devops, reporting

I want to be able to do a retrospective report for the previous quarter to sum up for each epic, feature, Story a sum of what it all took. so we can understand our quarter. I see there isn't a way in the queries to do this. Based on my research it seems like we need to do it in power bi. Is this correct? is there a simpler way since I don't have access to power BI. All I can think of is export to excel or export to a db and create a query (this is my best skill option).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need the [Rollup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops) feature in DevOps. Rollup provides summed values of select fields for all child work items of a parent. But the system doesn't support rollup of the Effort, Story Points, or Size fields across product backlogs and portfolio backlogs.

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops#other-tools-that-support-rollup) also mentioned other methods to obtain rollup of additional data fields in Azure DevOps work tracking data. Power BI is one of methods. With [Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops), a suite of business analytics tools, you can pull data from Analytics, generate reports, and customize them to meet your needs.

If Power BI and [existing charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/support-rollup-of-work-and-other-fields?view=azure-devops#work-item-query-charts-and-rollup) are not available for you, then you can try to use the extensions. For example [Canarys RollUp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=canarysautomationspvtltd.canarysrollup) and [Query Tile Extended](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aurelien-sudre.querytile-extended). Just create a query to find out the work items of the previous quarter. Then add the extension widget in your dashboard and configure it with the created query.

[image]

If all the above cannot meet your requirements, then I'm afraid that you'll have to export the data (to excel or a db as you mentioned) and create query/filter based on it.

Comment: @greektreat May I know if the answer helps? Just wanted to see if I could do anything for you.